# C in VS Code error. The preLaunchTask 'C/C++:gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cs50

I am really new to C and VS Code and came across this error when I try to compile the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    string answer = get_string("What's your name? ");
    printf("hello, %s", answer);
}
```

[This error shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBRr4.png), but when I press "Show Errors" it says that I don't have any and when I press "Debug Anyway" it shows [another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Qlc.png),  saying that there is no such file as hello.c and sends me to **launch.json**

The **launch.json**:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "c:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/CS50/lecture1",
      "program": "c:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/CS50/lecture1/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It only started appearing after I installed cs50.h and if I try to run a file without it, then it's fine.

I would appreciate any help, thanks!